# How to make a login for Alexa Linked Account in WebApi 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, alexa-skills-kit

I need to connect my website as a linked account in my Alexa Skills, i have yet a login in my website which makes a request to the following API and set a JWT token in the cookies like this:

```
   <HttpPost()>
    <Route("login")>
    Public Function GetLogin(data As Utenti.Login)
        If data.username = "" Or data.password = "" Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim utenti As Utenti = New Utenti
        Return utenti.UserExists(data.username, data.password)

    End Function
```

How could i reuse that API to link my website account to Alexa Skills as i have to retrive some claims from JWT token when a request from Alexa will be made to my website API to request some data?

I have yet tryed to make a linked like this:

And in my Alexa app the website is actually opened but when i login it's just login inside the website without linking it to Alexa

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation is not clear, but your mention of cookies makes it seem like you're on the wrong track. You need an OAuth2 authorization flow.

If I login AT Amazon (Authentication), I fill out my login and password, they confirm them, set a cookie, and I have access to the site, logged in as me.

If I use Login WITH Amazon (Authorization), I go to a site/app that sends a special request AND me to Amazon's OAuth server in a browser, webView, or inAppBrowser. Amazon might make me login if I'm not cookied (to be sure it's me), then says "do you want to give this site/app permission to access these specific functions and data on your behalf?" If I say yes, Amazon redirects me back to the site/app and puts either a short-lived access token (Implicit Grant) or a code (Authorization grant) in the URL when it sends me back.

The site/app then uses the access token (or uses the code to get a renewable access token) to access the specific Amazon APIs I granted permissions for it to use.

So if you're going to your site, logging in, a cookie is set, and nothing more... that's not the right process for account linking.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/account-linking-concepts.html